# Time taken by the Procedure

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to find the time taken by the procedure to complete. I need to even track the difference in milliseconds/nanoseconds. I am looking to introduce some timestamp functions in between like

```
 start_time;
 ....<transactions>
 end_time;
```

using sysdate, I am unable to capture the time taken in seconds.
Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Add this before your query

`set statistics time on`

Comment: `sysdate` returns a date to the second so I'm not sure what you mean by "unable to capture the time taken in seconds".  If you want milliseconds (or nanoseconds depending on the operating system), you'd need to use timestamps and the `systimestamp` function.

Comment: Are you looking to instrument and log all your calls or are you trying to profile a run of your program?

Answer (score 3):

You may try `DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME`

> This function determines the current time in 100th's of a second. This
>   subprogram is primarily used for determining elapsed time. The
>   subprogram is called twice – at the beginning and end of some process
>   – and then the first (earlier) number is subtracted from the second
>   (later) number to determine the time elapsed.

**Syntax**

```
DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME 
  RETURN NUMBER;
```

**Return Values**

> Time is the number of 100th's of a second from the point in time at
>   which the subprogram is invoked.

**An example**

```
Declare
  l_start number;
  l_end number;
Begin
  l_start := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME ;
  -- transactions
  l_end := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME ;
  dbms_output.put_line('elapsed: ' || (l_end - l_start) / 100 || 'secs');
END;
```

Comment: +1 I use this quite often. Just a caveat, however from the docs: *Numbers are returned in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647 depending on platform and machine, and your application must take the sign of the number into account in determining the interval. For instance, in the case of two negative numbers, application logic must allow that the first (earlier) number will be larger than the second (later) number which is closer to zero. By the same token, your application should also allow that the first (earlier) number be negative and the second (later) number be positive.*